# Android Create Project Name Attribute

Tags: android, command-line-interface

I've been playing the CLI around creating Android projects. It seems to work ok, except that the -n, or --name parameter is ignored, and instead the strings.xml is created with the -a/--activity value. For instance

```
android create project -t android-19 -p ./platforms/android -k com.ex.Foo -a FooActivity -n Foo
```

I would expect in the strings.xml to see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Foo</string>
</resources>
```

But instead I see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">FooActivity</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: -n denotes the *project* name and doesn't necessarily relate to the app name. You can have a project name "XYZ" but then set the app_name to be "ABC" or anything else you want. When you publish your app it will appear on Google Play as an app called "ABC" and that's how it will appear on a device in the app launcher screen. The project on your dev machine will still be called "XYZ" however. It seems the 'android' CLI isn't particularly flexible when it comes to all aspects of creating a new project / app.

Comment: The thing is that the "ABC" you mention is utterly lost. It doesn't exist in the Manifest or anything. Sure, I can manually change the files, but my question was more, "Am I doing it right, and if not, why?"

Comment: Actually, the ABC does seem to have been retained for one single use -- it is the project name in the build.xml generated for you.